# Jupyter Notebook 404 After Login

Tags: apache, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter, proxypass

So I'm trying to setup a notebook instance on my server. 
Ubuntu 16.04
jupyter notebook is being run from an account set up to only do that. 
Apache 2 is using ProxyPass to pass all requests to the appropriate port.

apache2.conf:

```
    ProxyPass /jupyter http://localhost:31415/jupyter
    ProxyPass /jupyter/api/kernels/http://localhost:31415/jupyter/api/kernels/
```

Although that second line, though recommend on some sites, seems to be of no consequence whether or not I comment it out.

About the jupyter config:

```
    c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/jupyter'
    c.NotebookApp.enable_mathjax = True  
    c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
    c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
    c.NotebookApp.port = 31415
```

The password has been hashed and is in the .json file.

This log shows me going to https://mydomain/jupyter, trying one incorrect password, then trying the correct password:

```
    [I 00:33:06.290 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jupyter/.jupyter
    [I 00:33:06.290 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
    [I 00:33:06.290 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
    [I 00:33:06.290 NotebookApp] http://localhost:31415/jupyter/
    [I 00:33:06.290 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
    [I 00:33:51.782 NotebookApp] 302 GET /jupyter/ (127.0.0.1) 1.10ms
    [I 00:33:51.940 NotebookApp] 302 GET /jupyter/tree? (127.0.0.1) 1.48ms
    [W 00:34:03.481 NotebookApp] 401 POST /jupyter/login?next=%2Fjupyter%2Ftree%3F (127.0.0.1) 2.68ms referer=http://mydomain/jupyter/login?next=%2Fjupyter%2Ftree%3F
    [I 00:34:10.460 NotebookApp] 302 POST /jupyter/login?next=%2Fjupyter%2Ftree%3F (127.0.0.1) 1.82ms
    [I 00:34:10.621 NotebookApp] Refusing to serve hidden directory, via 404 Error
    [W 00:34:10.634 NotebookApp] 404 GET /jupyter/tree? (127.0.0.1) 14.33ms referer=http://mydomain/jupyter/login?next=%2Fjupyter%2Ftree%3F
```

You can see that main 404 error there. In my browser, the result was:
[404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ98A.png)

But I was able to make it through the login prompt.

Comment: Is there an actual malfunction, or are you just wondering about the 404 in the log? The local directory `.jupyter` looks like a bad idea. IIRC, dot-prefixed directories are considered hidden. Start the notebook server in a directory /home/jupyter/notebook/ instead of /home/jupyter/.jupyter/ and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is an older one, but on follow up this was a hidden directory problem, I had not accounted for the notebook running in the directory I was in at execution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. I don't know why it's going to happen, But I solved this problem by changing the port number.This is a real metaphysics.